# Ansible get playbook path

Tags: bash, ansible, yaml

I would like to get the path of where an Ansible YAML file is.

Does it exist an equivalent way of BASH command `dirname $0` in Ansible (without using shell task to execute `dirname $0`)?

Comment: Would `{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'PWD') }}` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ansible are [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) available. The equivalent would be to use [`playbook_dir`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-playbook_dir)

> *The path to the directory of the current playbook being executed. NOTE: This might be different than directory of the playbook passed to the `ansible-playbook` command line when a playbook contains a `import_playbook` statement.*

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show Playbook Directory
    debug:
      msg: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
```

will result into the output of

```yaml
TASK [Show Playbook Directory] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: /home/user/test
```